# Does message exchange between View and ViewModel break MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I have a complex View with UserControls that need to be updated. The easiest way of doing so, as I see it so far, is by using message mediation service as MVVM Light Messenger. However in this case I will need to have some handling code in my View, which isn't ideal in MVVM.

Does message exchange between View and ViewModel break MVVM pattern?

Edit: to clear things a little, for example, If I need to programatically add a new UserControl to my View signalled by ViewModel. How can that be achieved?

Comment: MVVM != no codebehind.  UI code should exist in your view.

Comment: @Will So how to signal the View about its UserControl updates then?

Comment: So how to signal the view about changes in the view? Not sure what you're asking there, as you do it however it makes sense.  If you're talking about communication between the view and view model, well, think of it this way... The VM represents the state of the application.  As the state changes (due to business logic or due to user action), the view model changes. The View reacts as it observes these changes. If the user changes the state via the view, these changes are typically transmitted to the VM via bindings. So, do it. Without a specific example, I can't be more clear on the subject.

Comment: @Will Sorry for the confusion, I've updated my question to be a little more specific. I cannot find a way of using binding for programmatic adding of UserControls to the view for instance.

Comment: You don't do this "programatically" in MVVM.  Your state is represented by your ViewModel and the Models it exposes on its surface.  The view is bound to these properties. When a binding updates, the View is coded to look for the most appropriate way to display the state to the user. This is typically done via DataTemplates.  See my answer here for a compact example http://stackoverflow.com/a/13807112/1228 is that what you're looking for?